# Image not cropping or resizing correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, imagick

I am trying to build a profile upload system. The user will upload an image, and right before they submit it, they'll have the opportunity to crop the image. I am using the cropbox image crop plugin, I'm also using jQuery validation plugin. Upon submission, the image will be cropped at full size, and then resized to 250px by 250px. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1mnhctr/) of what I have HTML and jQuery wise.

**HTML**

```
<form class="avatar_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="avatar" style="display: block; margin-top: 20px" type="file" name="avatar">
  <input type="hidden" name="width">
  <input type="hidden" name="height">
  <input type="hidden" name="yValue">
  <input type="hidden" name="xValue">

  <div id="stage"></div>
  <input id="upload-btn" type="submit" value="Update profile picture" name="upload">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".avatar_form").validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  rules: {

    avatar: {
      required: true,
      extension: "jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG",
      filesize: 100000000,
      minImageSize: {
        width: 250,
        height: 250
      }
    },
  },

  messages: {


    avatar: {
      required: "You have to provide an image.",
      extension: "We only accept .jpg and .png images.",
      filesize: "Your image size should not exceed 100KB",
      minImageSize: "Your image must be at least 250px by 250px."

    },
  },

});

var $form = $('.avatar_form'),
  $upload_btn = $form.find('upload-btn');
$form.find('#avatar').change(function() {
  var $avatar = $(this),
    $imgBox = $("#stage");

  $avatar.removeData('imageSize');
  $imgBox.hide().empty();

  var file = this.files[0];

  if (file.type.match(/image\/.*/)) {
    $upload_btn.attr('disabled', true);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $imgBox.append($img).show();

        $avatar.data('imageSize', {
          width: $img.width(),
          height: $img.height()
        });

        $img.css({
          display: "none"
        });

        $upload_btn.attr('disabled', false);

        validator.element($avatar);
      });
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    validator.element($avatar);
  }
});



$(function() {

  $("#avatar").on('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 250,
          height: 250
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {
          $(".width").val(results.cropW);
          $(".height").val(results.cropH);
          $(".yvalue").val(results.cropY);
          $(".xvalue").val(results.cropX);
        });
      });

      $('#stage').append($img);

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
}, 'File size must be less than {0}');

$.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
  var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
  return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height);
}, function(minSize, element) {
  return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_FILES["avatar"], $_POST["width"], $_POST["height"], $_POST["xValue"], $_POST["yValue"]))
            {
                $name = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];

                $temp_name = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];


                            $nameExt = explode('.',$name);
                            $nameExtension = $nameExt[1];

                            $name = $_SESSION["id"] . "." . $nameExtension;
                            $target_avatar_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/profiles/images/avatars/$name";


                                    $xValue = $_POST["xValue"];
                                    $yValue = $_POST["yValue"];
                                    $image = new Imagick($temp_name);
                                    $image->cropImage($_POST["width"], $_POST["height"], $xValue, $yValue);
                                        $image->resizeImage(250,250, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true);

                                        $image->writeImage($target_avatar_file);
                                        $username = $_SESSION["Username"];
                $query_file = "/profiles/images/avatars/$name";
                $db->query("UPDATE Users SET image = '$query_file' WHERE Username = '$username'");
            }
```

The jQuery validation part works correctly, but what doesn't is the PHP part. Once the user submits the image, it'll be cropped, resized, and then moved to my server. Moving the file to the server works, but cropping the image and resizing doesn't work correctly. When I upload an image, the image gets resized to 250px by 167px and doesn't get cropped properly for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$image->resizeImage(250,250, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true);
```

...seems to be redundant, and it *may* be causing a *proportional* resize of the *original* image. That would explain why the width is correct but not the height (for an image that is taller than it is wide, you'd probably see the inverse).

It seems to me like you just need the `$image->cropImage(...)` call.

**Update**:

The [Imagick::cropImage function](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php) takes the width and height of the *crop region* and the x/y of the top-left corner. What you're passing instead is the width/height of the *full image*, not the crop rectangle, so depending on what your `xValue` and `yValue` is, you're essentially selecting a crop rectangle that's beyond the boundaries of the image canvas.

Comment: The reason why I need this line, is because cropImage(...) only crops the image. For example, Ajax will relay the width, height, x and y coordinates to PHP, but the width and height that's being relayed is not the actual width and height of what's being shown to the user, it's actually much larger. The width and height that get relayed will be bigger than 250px 250px.

Comment: Do those values at least form a square?

Comment: The values are the same as the image. If I upload a 600 x 400 image, the $_POST["width"] will be 600 and $_POST["height"] will be 400 as well

Comment: I see; I think you're calling the API incorrectly, then. Just to clarify, if width and height are the original image width and height, what does the x & y value represent?

Comment: (it's just not clear what the data you're posting back represents)

Comment: I didn't make an Ajax call, could that be it?

Comment: Whether it's Ajax or not shouldn't matter; what matters is what the post data looks like and how you're using it.

Comment: I just noticed some mistakes in my jQuery. I am giving the values to $(".width"), $(".height"), and so on, but they don't exist. In my HTML, I haven't classes for those fields. I did now, but I am still getting the same error, even though when I console.log the widths and heights of the images, they turn out to be small now. An image I'm testing that has 600px width, is now 400px

Comment: Removing the resizeImage now, still gives me a 600 x 400 image, meaning the POST data is not changing for some reason...